# Yii value from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, gridview, yii

i need to get the value of a variable in a javascript function to put it in a textfiled.

Javascripts function:

```
function obtenerArrendatario(){
    arrendatario_id = $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('arrendatario');
    alert(arrendatario_id);
}
```

The alert give me the id of the selected row but i need to put the id in the textfield to save/create the form

Gridview

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'zf_arrendatarios_arrendatario_id'); ?>
    <?php 
        $arrendatarios = new ZfArrendatarios;
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',
            array(
            'id'=>'arrendatario',
            'selectableRows'=>1,
            'selectionChanged'=>'obtenerArrendatario',
            'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
            'dataProvider'=>$arrendatarios->search(),
                'filter' => $arrendatarios,
            'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
            'columns'=>array(       
                array('name'=>'arrendatario_id_personal', 'header'=>'DNI',),
                array('name'=>'arrendatario_nombre', 'header'=>'Nombre'),
                array('name'=>'arrendatario_email', 'header'=>'Email'),   
            ),
        ));
        ?>
        <?php
        echo $form->textfield($model,'zf_arrendatarios_arrendatario_id',array('class'=>'input input_r input_pryk', 'value'=>$arrendatario));
    ?> 
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'zf_arrendatarios_arrendatario_id'); ?>
</div>
```

So i need that id that the function capture to fill my textfield.

I tried

```
$arrendatario= "<script> document.write(arrrendatario_id) </script>";
```

But it print me the string not the value.

Comment: are you want to store value in textfield with name of `zf_arrendatarios_arrendatario_id`?

Comment: Yes, fill the textfiled with the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, you can set the textfield value in below js function

```
function obtenerArrendatario(){
    arrendatario_id = $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('arrendatario');
   $(".input_pryk").val(arrendatario_id );// input_pryk should be class for this text field alone.
}
```

Then you will get in controller while submitting the form.